# SSL with Basic Auth on Spring Security

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, spring-security, basic-authentication

I develop the rest api and need auth on each request. 
I want to make server do basic auth via ssl. I've found topic  [how configure ssl on tomcat](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-set-up-ssl-on-tomcat.html?page=1) but all topics about organization of basic auth for Java EE.

I use Spring and know about Spring Security but not a lot. 
How can I set up basic auth via spring-security?

Or how convert this [web.xml](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/tomcat/how-do-i-use-basic-authentication-with-tomcat/web.xml) to Java based type for class that implements WebApplicationInitializer.

Also I'll be happy if hear about best practice for secure REST API and technologies for it.